# Specify a table prefix for MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prefix

In CakePHP, I can specify a prefix in my database configuration, i.e. "so_", so that every model looks for its table under this prefix.

Is something similar possible in Rails, too? That is, can several programs share one database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might try the following in `environments.rb`:
In the config section add the following code

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "so_"
```

Comment: Works perfectly as of version 2.1.2.

Comment: It appears in 5.0 there is `config/environments/development.rb`, `production.rb` and `test.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily specify your own table name for each model with the set_table_name method:

```
class Mouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "so_mice"
end
```

But you have to do it for each model, I don´t know of any global configuration option.

Comment: Can I be sure that the database isn't dropped when I do fancy `rake db`-things?

Comment: As long as you don't do a "rake db:reset" or "rake db:migrate:reset" the database won't be dropped.
Best way to prevent unintended database dropping is to not give the right to the user in question.